# dyld: Library not loaded: libqscintilla2.5.dylib

Tags: c++, qt, macos, makefile, qmake

I'm trying to use QScintilla on MacOS X, I added

```
LIBS += -lqscintilla2
```

in the .pro, with this quite simple code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <Qsci/qsciscintilla.h> 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QsciScintilla *qscintilla = new QsciScintilla;

    qscintilla->show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

(Im using QtCreator btw)

Here is the error :

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libqscintilla2.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/lubethan/cxx-proj/NightPad/NightPad.app/Contents/MacOS/NightPad
  Reason: image not found
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I copied the .dylib into /etc/lib/, it works now, but I'd like to make the app distributable...

Comment: +1 for bringing attention to the fact that this problem really bites you when it comes time to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use otool to find the dependencies. Then you can use install_name_tool to change the path of the library to a relative one. More details here. http://blogs.oracle.com/dipol/entry/dynamic_libraries_rpath_and_mac